# Why does post increment operator not work although preincrement does work in this code?

Tags: c, stack-overflow, post-increment, pre-increment

I am really new to programming (I'm an electronics and comm. engineer) and I am not able to figure out why one program works and the other one doesn't.

I'd like to get a good understanding of recursive functions before going any further with my learning. I would appreciate any help regarding this.

I know the difference between the x++ and --x. But in this context of this program, I thought both of these programs should run the same way. But they don't.

```
void rec(int x)
{
    if(x>0)
        rec(x--);
    printf("%d",x);
}

int main()
{
    rec(4);
    _getch();

} /*This doesn't work. And shows a stackoverflow */

void rec(int x)
{
    if(x>0)
        rec(--x);
    printf("%d",x);
}

int main()
{
    rec(4);
    _getch();

} /*This gives a proper output as expected*/ 
/*The output is 00123*/
```

Thanks!

**P.S:** Forgive me if this is a trivial or stupid question, but I am stuck on this and I thought this is the best place I can look for help.

Comment: You really should enable warnings and debugging info at compilation time (e.g. compiling with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux), and you should learn to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux), notably step-by-step execution and displaying of data.

Comment: I'm currently using MS Visual Studio (I used to use Turbo C++). I had started programming a couple of weeks ago. I had read up a little bit before that. I think there should be a debugging tool in Visual Studio but I haven't figured out where yet. But thanks for the input. I use this tool because my university uses it for teaching purposes.

Comment: 'I know the difference between the x++ and --x' -- Nope. One should not assume that one knows the very thing that one is trying to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void rec(int x) {
    if (x>0)
        rec(x--);
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

This will recurse forever (or at least until you exhaust your stack space). `x--` means use the *current* value of `x`and *then* decrement it.

In other words, let's call `rec` with the parameter 20. That's greater than zero, so it will in turn call `rec` again with the current value of 20 *then* decrement `x` (but effectively *after* the call returns.

Hence you're forever calling `rec` with the value of 20, which is why you're blowing out your stack.

If you change `x--` to `--x`, it decrements `x` *before* passing it to the function, hence it will go `20, 19, 18, ... 1, 0`, at which point it will run back up the stack printing all those values.

If you had put a `printf ("before: %d\n", x)` before the `if` statement, you would have seen a lot of `20` lines output to the screen.

Comment: While this certainly answers the question, I would say that the root of the problem is that ++ operators mixed with other expressions is a very effective way to create bugs. The code `if(x>0){ x--; rec(x); }` would have worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

x-- calls the function with the old value of x (before decrement). So you will get an infinite recursion of it calling itself with the same value. --x calls the function with the new (decremented)) value of x, so it eventually hits the x > 0 condition.

Another way to investigate this is to do the following:

```
int a, b;
a = b = 1;

printf("--a: %d b--: %d\n", --a, b--); // Output is --a: 0 b--: 1
```